# Find value in DataFrame (with read_excel) with pandas and 'loc', but not case sensitive

Tags: python, pandas, case-sensitive

I'm a beginner with Pandas (python). I'm using it importing a xlsx file.

The read_excel function is fine, but when I search a string value, it's return only the exact pattern (case sensitive).

I can't find in the documentation how to do that ignoring the case.
My code :

```
def read_food(self):
    if len(self.food_filename) > 0 and os.path.exists(self.food_filename):
        self.data_frame = pd.read_excel(self.food_filename, skiprows=3, sheet_name=self.sheetname_ingredients, usecols='B,D,G,J', names=['name', 'food_ingredient_for_net_weight', 'foodges_ingredient_for_ingested_weight', 'food_transport_ingredient_weight'], index_col=None, header=None, dtype={'name':str, 'food_ingredient_for_ingested_weight':float, 'food_ingredient_for_ingested_weight':float, 'food_transport_ingredient_weight':float})
    else:
        raise Exception('[read_food] : food filename/file not exists')
```

But, when I search a value with that :

```
return self.data_frame.loc[self.data_frame['name'] == ingredient]
```

only the values with the exact case returns... :(

Have you an idea please ?
Thanks

F.

Comment: Did you press F to pay respects? You can use `df[df['name'].str.contains(ingredient, case=False)]`

Comment: I believe you want `self.data_frame.loc[self.data_frame['name'].str.lower() == ingredient.lower()]`

Comment: Thanks for kindness :))), but I've already testing that (no need to use str.replace). `taxo.data_frame[taxo.data_frame['name'].str.contains("Courgette", case=False)]` return error : "cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values" and `taxo.data_frame.loc[taxo.data_frame['name'].str.lower() == "COURGETTE".lower()]` return error : 'Could not operate 'tolower : ' with block values must be str, not float'. The column 'name' have alphabetics and numeric characters